# How to store global parameter in a flask application?

Tags: flask

I am building a flask web app and I want to store some parameters that would be able to be changed in an admin interface.

I was wondering how to store these parameters. I first thought about using a database, but each parameters may be different so I couldn't find a table scheme that would match my problem. I also thought about using a text a file, but I don't know which format would be the best.

What can you suggest me to store these parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save them in **json** format, many databases support saving a **json** inside a field, alternatively you can save it in text format and then load it in a **json object**.

Comment: Would it be better in term of speed to use a database or a file ? And is there any python module that can achieve that ?

Comment: For the management of json objects in python you have the standard python library available. Regarding storage, if each user has their own configuration, I suggest you save it in a database.

Comment: The python library to use depends on the database you are connecting to. If you use an orm (for example SQLAlchemy) the orm itself will handle the data.

Comment: I use SQLAlchemy as an ORM, but this won't be a config file for each user, it will be global settings, like front page text or things like that.